# Why are const or let not needed when declaring a property with "this"?

Tags: javascript, declaration

In a class constructor, why are `const` and `let` not used ?

```
class Rectangle {
  constructor(width, height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.area = width * height;
    this.widthScaled;
    this.heightScaled;
  }

  scale(x) {
    this.widthScaled = this.width * x;
    this.heightScaled = this.height * x;
  }
}
```

**Why shouldn't it be :**

```
    const this.area = width * height;
    let this.widthScaled;
```

?

Comment: because you are not declaring a new variable but modifying properties of an already existing variable

Comment: `const` and `let` are needed for declaring variables. `this.foo` is  *an object property*, not a variable

Answer (score 3):

That's because you're not creating a new variable, you're just adding/changing a property to the current instance (this).
To elaborate with an example, Imagine this:

```
const x = {};
x.prop = 10;
```

as you can see, we added `prop` as a property to `x` object. Same thing happens when you use `this`;
`This.width = width` simply adds a property named `width` to current Rectangle instance (with the value inside `width` parameter), so no new variable is created.

Answer (score 0):

As previous speakers said, you are not creating new variable but modify alredy existing one. Your constructor is 'function' that creates new object and inside it you modify it's(this keyword) properties:

```
  constructor(width, height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.area = width * height;
    this.widthScaled;
    this.heightScaled;
  }
```

The equivalent in the javascript without using classes would look like this:

```
    var myObject = {};
    myObject.width = width;
    myObject.height = height;
    myObject.area = width * height;
    myObject.widthScaled;
    myObject.heightScaled;
```

But because you are using class you can create it like this and create many rectangles:

```
    var rectangle1 = new Rectangle(3,4);
    var rectangle2 = new Rectangle(5,10);
    const rectangle3 = new Rectangle(22,11);
```